# What is the best way to write code to run with elevated privileges when using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using SPServices(Javascript Library) to read Sharepoint list data on the client side (i.e., Mainly '/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx'). Everything was fine till I have read permissions on the Sharepoint List.

Suddenly when the permissions are removed on a couple of lists, my code begins to fail as the code is getting executed with the current users context.

I wanted to 
(a) execute the code with elevated privileges 
(b) at the same time allow my client only to read the data.

I had some idea like to have a SOAP Wrapper Service for 'Sharepoint List Service' (i.e., Lists.asmx) where I consume the original service (i.e., Lists.asmx) and the code block gets executed with elevated privileges. Now, the SPService calls will be replaced with calls to my custom SOAP service. But, I am not sure how to implement the same.

At the same time I feel the above solution may solve only problem (a) but the problem (b) remains still.

What is the best strategy to read data even if no privileges are assigned to a list for the current user as the data is sensitive?

May be this is why 'App Model in Sharepoint 2013' has been introduced where the app can have permissions on lists and not the user.

Please help me in addressing the above situation.

Comment: Which kind of App do you have? SharePoint-Hosted or Provider-Hosted?

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2010 not 2013 and I have pages with ajax calls directly consuming the Sharepoint List Service. I wanted to stop users from investigating the ajax calls and find a way to query the data from the list.